# Bootstrap navBar have unexpected design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm just try to use bootstrap

and It give me wrong format for nav bar

when I use this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head 
content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media 
 queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js">
   </script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">
  </script>
<![endif]-->


  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-
   toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-
    expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
     role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span 
     class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
     </nav>

          <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
         <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
   <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as 
      needed -->
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
   </html>
```

that what I get.
[Navbar not shown click to see the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6grC.png)

However I do some research, and one post on stackOverflow recommend to add this peace of code,

```
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  integrity="sha384-
BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
```

when I use it, I get wrong shape of navBar as following :-

the code after Update

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->

        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <!-- Bootstrap new add-on -->

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">



      <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
      <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->


    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>





        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

the drop menu appear and it's working but the shape of the navbar is not normal

[very large navbar click to see the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hQw3.png)

the question is : 1- how To get normal navbar shape ?

```
              2- why navbar appear after use this extra line ?
```

Comment: try to use https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
and https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js see if at least it is working?

Comment: do you mean, just add this links on the <head> </head> tag

Comment: yes try to add those into your head tag https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/oyp5dq7k/ might be your ref path not finding it

Comment: @ochi Per the Bootstrap 3 'Getting Started', 1.12.4 is the recommended version of jQuery.

Comment: So if we pop your code into Bootply the expected results are there ( https://www.bootply.com/MwBr6fdHJc ), which likely means the issue is on your end... perhaps a malformed path to the Bootstrap CSS, JS, or jQuery.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue either.  Are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Me and others are unable to recreate the error, so I believe the problem is on your end, probably to do with your browser. Here are a few things you can try:

- Press ctrl + f5
- If that doesn't work, then press f12 to pull up developer tools, then when you 
  right click on the refresh icon near the URL bar, you get 3 options, click the 
  one that says "Clear cache and Hard Reload". This reloads everything, and 
  clears the cache.

To prevent future errors of this sort, you can go into developer tools (or right click > inspect), then click the "Network" tab at the top of the window that pops up, and there should be an option right below that tab that says "Disable cache", make sure that's checked. This will help prevent the problem, but could also make pages load a little slower, so you can turn it off afterwards if you need.